# Syntax error or access violation on MySQL geometry data type

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am working with datatype geometry on MySQL. I try to query from the page. I got the error.

How to fix? Could you please help?

Error here:

> "An exception occurred while executing '

```
SELECT  t.`road_id`, t.`road_ref_num`, t.`chainage`, t.`road_name`,
        ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(t.`road_wkt`, ?::int)) as geom
    FROM  gis_ruralroads_t1 t
    WHERE  (t.road_ref_num LIKE ?)
      AND  (ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(?, ?),
                     ST_Point(?, ?)), ?), ST_Srid(t.`road_wkt`)) && t.`road_wkt`
           )
```

> with params [32648,
>               "%0806T1001%", 5579.905, 1088581.723, 1029359.857, 1650396.77,
>               32648]
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '::int)) as geom FROM gis_ruralroads_t1 t WHERE (t.road_ref_num LIKE '%0806T1001%' at line 1"

Best,
Loy

Answer (score 0):

It is pointing right at `::int`.  MySQL does not have any syntax like that.  Simply remove those 5 characters.

In general, you can trust that an integer will be correctly substituted, even if quotes are added:

```
ST_Transform(t.`road_wkt`, ?)
```

turns into this after substitution:

```
ST_Transform(t.`road_wkt`, '32648')
```

The apostrophes won't hurt.